# Routing in Angular 4 - Nested Children

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I am trying to implement multiple levels of nested children and was wondering if someone would be able to help. The issue I am having at the moment is that when I have a nested child route it needs to contains another `<router-outlet>` and therefore two screens appear on one page.

### Code

*app-routing*

```
  { path: 'claim/:id', component: ClaimDashboardComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Claim' }, children: [
    { path: 'details', component: ClaimDetailsComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Details' } }
  ]}
```

Now as you can see when the user hits the URL for example `claim/1` then the  `ClaimDashboardComponent` will load. I then want to be able to click on a box inside the Component which will then load the details for that claim.

The issue i seem to be having is that I have to add a `<router-outlet>` to the `ClaimDashboardComponent` so when i load the URL `claim/1/details` both components seem to be appearing.

I just want the `ClaimDetailsComponent` to load and the `ClaimDashboardComponent` HTML to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ path: 'claim/:id' children:[
    {path:'', component: ClaimDashboardComponent, 
                  data: { breadcrumb: 'Claim' }},
    { path: 'details', component: ClaimDetailsComponent, 
                  data: { breadcrumb:'Details' } }
  ]}
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.